# Check if Wildfly Server is running with my app?

Tags: jboss, server, wildfly, state

I would like to know how can I check if my Wildfly Server is running and the WebApp has been deployed?

Currently I check only if the server is running.

```
public static boolean checkServerAvailable() {
    try {

        String url = Constants.URL_APP + ":" + Constants.APPSERVER_PORT;

        HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
        // note : you may also need
        // HttpURLConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false)
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url)
                .openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");

        if (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            return true;
        }

        else
            return false;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But I need to know if the Wildfly server also my web app deployed successull.

Answer (score 3):

To start with you could add your webapp url to the url you're creating above.  Instead of connecting to, for example, http://localhost:8080/ and looking for a HTTP 200 response, you could connect to http://localhost:8080/yourApp and do the same.  That implies that you have something at the root context to respond.

An arguably better solution would be to have a "heartbeat" or "status" service in your web application.  This would be something like http://localhost:8080/yourApp/status.  The method or service could just return a 200 implying that the service is up.  But it could also really check that your application is healthy.  For example, it could check available memory or make sure that the database is up or a multitude of other things.  The code you show would just use the full URL of the status service.

Comment: Well, you surely can check, using the administration console, whether the web application was deployed. Can it be that WildFly has no other service providing this information?

Comment: +1 to adding a status endpoint. On it, you can check not only if the application is deployed, but if it's healthy as well. On this status endpoint, a sanity check on the DB connection and other dependency services could be performed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the management API provided by WildFly. The API is described here for different versions of WildFly.

For WildFly9 - See  https://wildscribe.github.io/Wildfly/9.0.0.Final/deployment/index.html

You could use following URL to check the status of deployment. You do need a management user for authentication.

**Standalone Mode:**

```
http://localhost:9990/management/deployment/<deployment_name>
```

**For domain mode:**

```
http://localhost:9990/management/host/<host_name>/server/<serer_name>/deployment/<deployment_name>
```

Sample JSON response (assuming you deployed an EAR file with some sub-deployments):

```
{
"content": [{
    "hash": {
        "BYTES_VALUE": "2gH7ddtUxsbzBJEJ/z4T1jYERRU="
    }
}],
"enabled": true,
"enabled-time": 1468861076770,
"enabled-timestamp": "2016-07-18 18:57:56,770 CEST",
"name": "myapplication.ear",
"owner": null,
"persistent": true,
"runtime-name": "myapplication.app.ear",
"subdeployment": {
    "myapplication.impl.jar": null,
    "myapplication.web.war": null
},
"subsystem": null
```

}

**Sample request using curl:**

```
curl --digest -D - http://localhost:9990/management --header "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"operation":"read-resource", "include-runtime":"true", "address":["deployment","myapplication.app.ear"] }' -u user:password
```

Comment: Is there a user (mgmt user) and password necessary?

Comment: @MarcMeister yes a management user is required for authentication.

Comment: And where did you activate the management user for the request for: http://localhost:9990/management/deployment/<deployment_name>   I need a function in my code which will do a request for the URL and give me a return true or false if the Server and app is running....

Answer (score 0):

I aws looking for something to check if wildfly is running, [here](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-wildfly-on-centos-7/#step-4-configure-systemd) I saw:

```
systemctl status wildfly
```

And also were so useful:

```
systemctl stop wildfly
systemctl restart wildfly
systemctl start wildfly
```